# Failling to load weights on my tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I've implemented and trained a resnet model on tensorflow.
I saved it that way :

```
save_path=saver.save(sess,"/home/.../model.ckpt",global_step=50)
        saver.save(sess,"/home/s.../model.ckpt",global_step=50)
```

On an other script I try to load it and to test it on some images.

My script is build like this:

```
files = [s for s in os.listdir(dossier_source+'/'+d) if s.endswith(".png") or(".jpeg")]
        print files.__len__()
        batch_size_arg=files.__len__()
        x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,IMAGE_WIDTH,IMAGE_HEIGHT,NUMBER_OF_CHANNELS], name='x-input')
        y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None], name='y-input')
        train_file =str(dossier_source+d+"/*.png")
```

I recreate all variables [..]

```
with tf.Session() as sess:

            sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())

            saver=tf.train.Saver()

            saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint(global_path))
            tab= sess.run('conv0/conv:0')
            print tab[0][0][0] #here is a little test that proves conv0 weights is the same as the ones i get on training

            for i in xrange(1):
                im_batch, lab_batch = sess.run([images_batch, labels_batch])

                curr=sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict={x: im_batch, y: lab_batch})
                top=sess.run(top_k_op ,feed_dict={x: im_batch, y: lab_batch})
                conf =sess.run(confusion,feed_dict={x: im_batch, y: lab_batch, })
                print "Results"

                print curr
                print conf
```

My problem is that even though conv0 show everytime the same weights, the confusion table and the results are different on each test on the very same images....

Am I doing something wrong when i load my weights and model ?

> EDIT:

With the latest tests, i realized that if I do

```
for i in xrange(3):
                im_batch, lab_batch = sess.run([images_batch, labels_batch])

                curr=sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict={x: im_batch, y: lab_batch})
                top=sess.run(top_k_op ,feed_dict={x: im_batch, y: lab_batch})
                conf =sess.run(confusion,feed_dict={x: im_batch, y: lab_batch, })
                print "Results"

                print curr
                print conf
```

on the very same batch of 3 images, I get different results aswell.

Comment: There is a difference of batchnorm in training and inference phase. Not sure, how you implemented it. But when using a `with tf.control_dependencies` for performing the non-gradient updates in the batch-norm layer you'll get different results as the batch-norm statistics changes between different sess.runs.

Comment: But even tho, the confusion matrix on the same 3 images should be the same on 3 different runs with the same restored model shouldn't they?
Would you need any details about my implementation?